# Slideshow in javascript

Tags: javascript

I did this slideshow, but when the images are changing sometimes there is a lag. The images are supposed to change every two seconds, but when I watch the behavior of the slideshow sometimes, the images take 4 seconds to change to another different image. 
How can I solve this please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var gallery = new Array("", "images/slide-show/company-image1.jpg", "images/slide-show/company-image2.jpg",
    "images/slide-show/company-image3.jpg", "images/slide-show/company-image4.jpg");

    var slideControl = gallery.length-1;

    var randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*slideControl);

    function slideShow(){

        var i;

        var randomControl;

        for(i=0; i<randomNumber; i++){

            randomControl = Math.ceil(Math.random()*slideControl);
        }

        document.getElementById("holder").src= gallery[randomControl];

        setTimeout("slideShow()",2000);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Please share your code with us. You have not provided even near enough data for us to help, so most people will just ignore your question and go to the next. If you want to be helped, please do your best to make the question easy on the people who are volunteering to answer it.

Comment: If your array `gallery` has an empty string, that will cause a pause.

Comment: Why would you cycle the call to random in the for loop? That will not make it any more random.. After all, `Math.random` is only going to generate a psuedo random number as it is.

Comment: might also not hurt to pre-load the images to avoid render delay

Comment: There's seriously so many javascript slideshow/carousel plugins already developed. Why you'd want to try to create your own is just strange.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has the chance of sliding to the same image that it's already on. So your random number generator will pick `2` even if you're already on `2`. Update your logic so that it cannot repeat the number that it's already on.

Answer (score 0):

what do you think about that:  http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/JTvVn/

for the HTML

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
      <img src="images/slide-show/company-image1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div>
      <img src="images/slide-show/company-image2.jpg">
      </div>
      <div>
      <img src="images/slide-show/company-image3.jpg">
      </div>
</div>
```

for the Javascript

```
 $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  2000);
```

and some CSS

```
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```